# Telergram Bot взаимодействие с сайтом

Tags: javascript, php

есть ли возможность с помощью телеграмм бота выполнить js код на сайте? Например я нажимаю кнопку в боте, и на сайте выполняется какое то действие, буду рад предложенным идеям

Comment: Что значит на сайте? на сервере где хостится сайт или в браузере на другом сайте?

Comment: Где хостится сам сайт

Comment: Что именно вы хотите сделать? пока что очень абстрактно, и похоже, если это одна из типовых задач с которыми я сталкивался, вы хотите админить сайт из телеги? проще всего напрямую в БД сайта лазить из бота

Comment: По сути да, админить сайт из телеги, выполнять какие либо действия на сайте с помощью этого бота

Comment: Ну тогда ответ там же, в комментарии выше, самый простой способ или подключатся к сайту по апи если таковое есть, или менять значения в базе данных сайта из бота, бот и сайт соответственно находятся в одной подсети или на одной машине (ну или вы знакомы с нат и понимаете о чем я)...

Comment: У вас есть материал который может помочь по изменению значений бд сайта из бота?

Comment: Полно, но мне пока не понятен уровень ваших знаний чтобы направить на более подходящий материал :) ну т.е. я могу кинуть ссылку с описанием апи телеграмма, но вероятней если бы вы могли это понять - у вас бы не возникло подобного вопроса.... Ну и я не в курсе что вы хотите админить, если это какойнить 1с битрикс - то проще апи или вообще плагин под битрикс... :) Далее на каком ЯП вы пишите? с какими библиотеками знакомы....?

Comment: Через php просто по нажатию inline кнопки в телеграмм боте изменить роль пользователя

Comment: Находите удобную для вас [библиотеку](https://github.com), или если прокачать скилл - читаете [апи телеграмма](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api), Определяетесь с движком сайта и тем где искать по нему документацию, пишите бота который будет делать что то по нажатию кнопки(не на сайте, просто отвечать например на нажатие кнопки), а потом читаете как изменить значение в БД сайта

Comment: Спасибо вам большое